# How to convert JSON to Parquet in Apache Beam using Java

Tags: java, json, apache-beam, parquet

I am trying to convert Json Data

```
{"col1":"sample-val-1", "col2":1.0}
{"col1":"sample-val-2", "col2":2.0}
{"col1":"sample-val-3", "col2":3.0}
{"col1":"sample-val-4", "col2":4.0}
{"col1":"sample-val-5", "col2":5.0}
```

and I need this to be converted in Parquet

then I wrote some code in Apache Beam

```
package org.apache.beam.examples;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.kitesdk.data.spi.JsonUtil;
import tech.allegro.schema.json2avro.converter.JsonAvroConverter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Pipeline pipeLine = Pipeline.create();
        PCollection<String> lines = pipeLine.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from("path-to-file"));

        File initialFile = new File("path-to-file");
        InputStream targetStream = Files.newInputStream(initialFile.toPath());
        Schema jsonSchema = JsonUtil.inferSchema(targetStream, "RecordName", 20);
        System.out.println(jsonSchema.getDoc());
        PCollection<String> words = lines.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                JsonObject parsedMap = gson.fromJson(c.element(), JsonObject.class);
//                out.output(parsedMap);
//                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parsedMap.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                JsonAvroConverter avroConverter = new JsonAvroConverter();
//                GenericRecord record =  avroConverter.convertToGenericDataRecord(parsedMap.toString().getBytes(), jsonSchema);

//                context.output(record);
            }
        }));
        pipeLine.run();
        //
//        pgr.apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write().via(ParquetIO.sink(schema)).to("path/to/save"));
        
    }
}
```

I am able to get line by line json but unable to convert it to Parquet the above code throws error
if you try to convert the Json to Parquet using

```
GenericRecord record =  avroConverter.convertToGenericDataRecord(parsedMap.toString().getBytes(), jsonSchema);
```

error due to this line

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:55)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: That last line is Avro, not Parquet. JsonAvroConverter class won't help you get Parquet from json, only `ParquetIO.sink` can do that

Comment: Yeah I am using ParquetIO.sink at the end of the code you will see a commented line

Comment: Yes, I see that, but it is commented out. What is the exact error you are getting when you uncomment it?

Comment: I update the error log can you check now

Comment: And also Isn't there any direct way to convert json to parquet as I am using GenericRecord to do so?

Comment: You shouldn't need Avro, no. I've used Spark, Pig or Hive all to convert JSON to Parquet. Beam should be able to, as well. But reading over the ParquetIO javadoc, maybe not. In any case, your error has nothing to do with Beam, so please create a [mcve] of just your Avro conversion process

Comment: I think your error is related to the fact that `jsonSchema` needs to be serializable inside the DoFn class. Instead, try inferring that schema on each line, or make a chain of multiple apply functions that return the JSONObject collection from the strings, then another to infer the schema and apply Avro converter, then end with the ParquetIO

Comment: +1 to @OneCricketeer, can you check the full stack trace and see why `serializeToByteArray` is invoked and what runner are you using? If it's inevitable, you have to make sure that your jsonSchema is serializable or infer the schema in the `process` itself.

Comment: @MohitKumar, did above solution resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, as @OneCricketeer said I need to serialize it. I created a new class and added as parameter construct and created it in `@Setup ` .

Comment: If you've got it working, feel free to give your solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new class and added as parameter construct and created it in @Setup.

```
Schema jsonSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString);
pipeLine.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from(options.getInput()))
                .apply("Convert Json To General Record", ParDo.of(new JsonToGeneralRecord(jsonSchema)))
                .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, jsonSchema))
```

````
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(JsonToGeneralRecord.class);

    private final String schemaString;
    private Schema jsonSchema;


    // constructor
    JsonToGeneralRecord(Schema schema) {
        schemaString = schema.toString();
    }

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        jsonSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString);
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonObject parsedMap = gson.fromJson(c.element(), JsonObject.class);
        logger.info("successful: " + parsedMap.toString());

        JsonAvroConverter avroConverter = new JsonAvroConverter();
        try {
            GenericRecord record = avroConverter.convertToGenericDataRecord(parsedMap.toString().getBytes(), jsonSchema);
            c.output(record);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error:  " + e.getMessage() + parsedMap);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}```
````